# Angular component code reuse strategy

Tags: git, angular

I have a large Angular 4 with many components.
I need to use the same components in a different project.
I don't want to duplicate the code and use in different project.
I can not seem to find a way to create component 'library' for angular.
I am leaning toward using git submodules to at least have on central place for all the consumers of the code.

Are there alternate better strategies someone knows of?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem and finally went for the solution to use a third-party angular-library builder, which works super fine. After building the library I publish it to our private npm repository and the other Angular CLI projects consume it like any other library.

I can recommend [angular librarian](https://github.com/gonzofish/angular-librarian) which is easy to set up, has a lot of smart automation process in building the library and a very active and helpful developer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

1. Organising your code in a **library**, see [this](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) for reference. Basically you'll need these commands:

> ```
> ng new my-workspace --create-application=false
> cd my-workspace
> ng generate library my-lib
> ```

2. Or you may try using new approach called **monorepo**. [Reference](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/core-concepts/why-monorepos)

> A monorepo is a single git repository that holds the source code for
> multiple applications and libraries, along with the tooling for them.